# XP WiFi connect failure: "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network"

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

Running Windows XP, I try to connect to a wifi network, but get the following error "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network". It never gives me the chance to enter the password.

This is a conventional wifi network, and I know it works, as my Linux box can connect to it just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article : [Fix “Windows was unable to find a certificate to log you on to the network”](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/windows-was-unable-to-find-a-certificate-to-log-you-on-to-the-network/).

The idea is to uncheck the `Enable IEEE 802.1x authentication for this network` for your wifi network in the Wireless Networks list.

Answer (score 1):

The  method in harrymc's answer didn't do it for me, and i've read somewhere it only works for WEP.

I had this problem with Win XP SP2

The options when right clicking the network connection and going to properties, included WPA and WPA-PSK but not WPA2  and WPA2-PSK (you will see the relevance of this soon). That is normal for SP2 to be missing those, though there is a patch.
In this screen after clicking properties, you see what security settings are available e.g. WEP, WPA, e.t.c.
[image]

Connecting wirelessly to a router.

When I tried to connect to one router, it worked.

When I tried to connect to another, it didn't work and gave that message  "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network"

This is the second time i've seen that, and both times the following solution worked(suggested by my ISP Zen).

Download and Run the following patch `KB917021`
Update for Windows XP (KB917021)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24561

Requirements Windows XP Service Pack 2

The download is called WindowsXP-KB917021-v3-x86-ENU.exe

That then adds options of WPA2 and WPA2-PSK

Then even when I choose WPA  it connected, but when I went back to the connections properties I see it had gone to WPA2. So, the message about not finding a certificate, was in my case, because the router was on WPA2 and Windows XP SP2 wasn't supporting that until I downloaded and ran that patch.

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine for new access points which support wpa2-psk2

Comment: @RezaRahmati I guess you mean this solution *makes it work* fine for wpa2

Comment: Yes I mean that

Comment: @RezaRahmati was that with SP2 or SP3 or other?

Comment: It was WinXP SP2