# Win XP - “Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network”

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, certificate

A friend of mine has an old Toshiba Satellite laptop. I just re-installed XP on it and I am trying to get the computer online via WIFI (WPA-PSK / AES).

When I try to connect I get the following error: “Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network”.

I have done my research. I am aware of the following answer: [XP WiFi connect failure: "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network"](https://superuser.com/questions/82224/xp-wifi-connect-failure-windows-was-unable-to-find-a-certificate-to-log-you-on). There's a plenty of post about this issue. I did try to disable the "IEEE 802.1x authentication for this network". Unfortunately, the option is greyed out there I can't disable it.

I also deleted my preferred networks and tried to connect to the network by clicking on the "Add button.." and manually adding the connection settings which allows me to disable to the "IEEE 802.1x authentication for this network". But I still get the  “Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network”.

So I connected to the i-net via an ethernet cable and updated the laptop Atheros AR5004x driver (as another post suggested). After the driver update, I tried to connect wirelessly. Still no luck.

I am running out of ideas how to get the computer online via my wifi.

Any tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XP WiFi connect failure: "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network"](http://superuser.com/questions/82224/xp-wifi-connect-failure-windows-was-unable-to-find-a-certificate-to-log-you-on)

Comment: @techie007 He specifically said he was aware of that question and that fix didn't apply to him.

Comment: @spiff Same question still.

Comment: have you checked the clock on the OLD toshiba.. is it showing the correct time and date.

Comment: @techie007 You're doing the site a disservice if you "close as dupe" a Question that sounded superficially similar because it triggered the same error message, but actually had a different root cause and thus required a different solution.

Comment: The issue in the question http://superuser.com/questions/82224/xp-wifi-connect-failure-windows-was-unable-to-find-a-certificate-to-log-you-on is not really identical to my questions. Besides the same warning message, the question author (Anirvan) mentioned the following: "It never gives me the chance to enter the password." That's not the problem I am experiencing. I do get prompted for the network password. Once I type it in and submit, I get the "Windows Was Unable To Find A Certificate To Log You On To The Network" warning message. I am trying to get tips how to get the laptop online.

Comment: @spiff I prefer that the same question not be asked again just because the existing accepted answer didn't work for this user, instead I suggest comments and bounties for more/better answers on the original.  But hey, there's a reason it's "_possible_ duplicate", and why it takes more than 1 vote to close.  Regardless, please don't suggest I'm doing a 'disservice to the site' for casting a vote on a site designed to have votes cast.

Comment: @Vasek Does it behave the same when tried with another wireless network?  Can other devices connect to this WiFi network?  Have you checked the WiFi router/AP to ensure it's not enforcing certificates?  Have you tried resetting the WiFi router/AP to factory defaults and see if it behave any differently?  Have you tried any other WiFi encryption and authentication types (WEP, WPA2, etc. -- configured on both ends) to see if they behave any better/differently?

Comment: Does XP have the latest SP and updates installed? Did you get the driver you used from Toshiba or some random driver site?  Exactly which Toshiba notebook do you have, and what router/AP are you using?  Perhaps if you try these things and report back with results and more specifics (edit your question to add them) it won't seem like it's just another vague version of the question marked as a dupe.

Comment: hi Spiff and techie007, thank you guys for your input. I was experiencing the same problem on other wireless networks, didn't reset my router, using WPA-PSK / AES on all network, didn't try other types, i have sp3 (i think that's the latest one for sp3)... I can't explain it but without changing anything, I was inexplicably able to connect without any warnings/errors.. it's still a mystery to me what was causing the issue... either way, thanks guys for your  tips and suggestions.